# How to connect domain clients to workgroup WSUS server

Tags: windows, domain, wsus, workgroup

We have a small domain that sits on the same net as a single workgroup host with WSUS server.
Is it possible to  get the clients to connect to the workgroup host WSUS server?

The WSUS has IIS7 and is running on Windows Server 2008 R2.

- On the WSUS server, am I supposed to set 'User group policy or registry' for clients, or update services console?
- With 'User group policy or registry' chosen, I used this tool (http://wsusworkgroup.codeplex.com/) to set the registry to workgroupWSUS
- The WSUS server is accessible (tested with) "workgroupWSUS/iuident.cab" in the browser
- wauaclt.exe /detectnow is failing contact the WSUS server.
- The WSUS is not showing any status reports from client computers.

Any assistance or confirmation that this is possible would be highly appreciated.

Comment: To clarify, you modified the Windows Update group policy to make domain clients point to this WSUS server, right?

Comment: @Nathan C I did not actually modify the group policy, so far I have only set registry settings on the clients via the linked application in my post. I am quite new to domain and network setups - Do I have to go and modify the group policy on the domain controller, or are the registry settings an alternative?

Comment: Um, put the WSUS server on the domain?

Comment: If you set the registry policy manually on the clients, you have to restart the Automatic Updates (wuauserv) service on them for it to take effect. Then try a wuauclt /detectnow. The WSUS server does not have to be on the domain.

Comment: @DanBig Unfortunately I can't put the WSUS on the domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry setting isn't the proper way to do this. You want a GPO with the WSUS settings on it. See this for details: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc720539(v=ws.10).aspx

The interesting bits are under Administrative Templates, expand Windows Components, and then click Windows Update.

Obviously, apply the GPO using your domain controller.

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I will give this a try and report/accept if I manage.